# Non-invocable member 'SaveSystem' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up a save and load system in unity, but I'm now getting this error when trying to call out the necessary functions.

```
public class SaveSystem
{ 
    public void Save()
    {
        AllData allData = new AllData();
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey", 
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        bf.Serialize(file, allData);
        file.Close();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        AllData allData = new AllData();

        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey", 
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            allData = (AllData)bf.Deserialize(file);

            file.Close();
        }
    }
}

public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    AllData allData = new AllData();

    public Start(){
        saveSystem.Load();
     }

     public Update(){
        saveSystem.Load();
      }
}
```

Comment: The class is `SaveSystem` but you are trying to invoke `saveSystem`; `c#` is case sensitive, but the error message doesnt match that issue; so I suspect that is not the real code.  Since it is a class and not marked static, you need to create an instance in order to use any of the methods.  There are a number of other issues not least of which is that `AllData` is (re)declared as local variables which sort of obviates these methods

Comment: The code in the question does not contain an invocation of `SaveSystem` or `saveSystem`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the member declaration of saveSystem in your Shop behaviour:

```
public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SaveSystem saveSystem = new SaveSystem();
    AllData allData = new AllData();

    public Start(){
        saveSystem.Load();
     }

     public Update(){
        saveSystem.Load();
      }
}
```

However just looking at your code above, it has numerous problems. One being that you are creating a new instance of AllData() in the Shop class, and in the Save() and Load() methods so you're not really achieving anything. You should keep one instance of AllData() in your Shop object, and pass this allData instance to your Save() method, and also set this.allData = saveSystem.Load() to reload it.

Good luck